# Error in code for header redirect

Tags: php, mysql, http-post, post-redirect-get

I have template.php file which gets include in each page , so now I want to add comment form to each page , I have added the form to template.php , only problem I was having is refresh causes duplicate entry in DB .So after some research I found POST REDIRECT GET method , so in template.php I have put form action to addcomment.php and in addcomment.php I have used the following code:

```
    <?php
require_once("appvars.php");
require_once("connectvars.php");
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc() === 1){
  $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
  $_GET = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_GET );
  $_COOKIE = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_COOKIE );
}
if (isset($_POST['commentsubmit']))
{
$type=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['type']));
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['username']));
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['useremail']));
$subject=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['subject']));
$comment=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['usercomment']));
$link=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['link']));
$query = "INSERT INTO comments (`type`,`name`,`email`,`subject`,`comment`,`date`,`link`) VALUES         ('$type','$name','$email','$subject','$comment',NOW(),'$link')";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('error query'); 


 header("Location: $link", 302);
   exit();
}
?>
```

I am getting this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/animalsw/public_html/addcomment.php:1) in /home/animalsw/public_html/addcomment.php on line 22

and also how to check if query worked properly or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 3):

Remove these spaces before     `<?php` and it will work (assuming you have no output in your included files)

> and also how to check if query worked properly or not.

You already check it. If query fails, it will trigger `or die('error query');`

Comment: @user995426: You should not redirect user if you want  him to know comment was posted

Comment: why so, I am using dis approach so that form doesn't get resubmitted on refresh , I think by using GET there is a way to let user no comment was sucessfully posted

Answer (score 0):

To add to what genesis said, make sure require_once("appvars.php");
require_once("connectvars.php") do not echo out any data. Once you start outputting something, you will get that error because you will be sending headers when you're already outputting the body.

Comment: everything is workin fine except how to tell user if comment has been submitted